# Porter Stemmer algorithm question

Tags: search, indexing, porter-stemmer

I am implementing a search application.
Corpus is large text documents.
During file process i'm tokenizing all the words and calling Porter Stemmer algorithm
Step1 (http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/csharp2.txt).

Step1 gets rid of plurals and -ed or -ing...

I noticed that a word like 'this' will be stemmed into 'thi'.

Is that normal operation of the algorithm ?
Since I wanted to tokenize the word 'this'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, my hunch is that `this` is considered as plural form in Porter Stemmer algorithm and reduced to `thi`.

I do not find an explicit reference to non-plural words ending with `s` in Porter's paper.

http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/def.txt

Comment: Yes, i need to go over the algorithm and see why.